# How can I round a column value with a JPA query?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I need to compare for equality on a number stored in the database as a floating point number (this has to support multiple databases and I haven't got any control over how it's stored), but of course equality will only get you so far with an approximated value, so I need to round the column value like this:

```
select * from x where round(col, 2) = ?;
```

Unfortunately I can't seem to find a way of doing that in JPQL. Is there any way to achieve this (without changing the database)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have two ideas to solve this problem:

1. make a [between](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) query
2. use a native query

Comment: +1 for between because it would mean that any index on `col` is still used.