# Round to 2 decimal places in hibernate query language

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hql

Hi can someone help me how to round to 2 decimal places in hql?
I can't find anything online. Below is my query:

```
Select p.amount as amt,p.desc from pay p, register r where r.type=?1 and r.code=?2;
```

I would be glad if someone can help on this.

Technology used: hibernate, spring, java, primefaces 4.0, oracle database

Comment: have you tried `select round(p.amount, 2) as amt, ...` basically you can also use sql functions in hql depends on which db you are using

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992384/how-can-i-round-a-column-value-with-a-jpa-query

Comment: @Jaiwo99 no it does not work. am using oracle database

Answer (score 2):

I have struggled with this a lot an finally found the following solution:

If you want to be more DB independent and specifically want to support Postgres or Oracle DB you can use the floor function for rounding which is pretty generic and does not leave much room for different implementations, meaning this will probably work with all databases (tested with Postgres and MySQL).

The snippet performs rounding to 2 digits and rounds by the absolute value. You can easily adapt this to your needs.

Regard the division by 100 using 100.0. This will insure that you always get a double as a result which is particularly important if you build a sum over the rounded values.

```html
floor(abs(value) * 100 + 0.5)/100.0 * sign(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
cast(value as decimal(9,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

use `FORMAT` function on property to 2 decimal point

```
Select FORMAT(p.amount,2) as amt,p.desc from pay p, register r where r.type=?1 and r.code=?2;
```

alternatively you can specify the same in mapping file as well like below

```
 <property name="amount">
        <column name="amount" scale="15" precision="3" sql-type="number(15,2)"/>
    </property>
```