# how to setting scale of selected numeric column on hql

Tags: hibernate, hql

Is there any way for this situation. On hql query I want to setting scale on select statement. I don't want to enter in loop for this.

```
SELECT "SUM(invoice.amount+invoice.latePaymentPenalty +invoice.latePaymentVat) AS paymentAmount\n"+
            "FROM File AS file \n" +
            "LEFT JOIN file.invoices AS invoice\n" +
```

you can see my hql query. this query returns to me numbers like 167,8352436...
I want to setting scale and this query returns like 167,83. Is that possible on hql? If it is, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round to 2 decimal places in hibernate query language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369306/round-to-2-decimal-places-in-hibernate-query-language)

Answer (score 0):

Juste use round :

```
"select round(sum(....),2) ..."
```

It works well for me and sql server